# When using draw_sprite command in game maker studio 2 animation runs at a ridiculously fast speed

Tags: gml, game-maker-studio-2

When using the draw_sprite code in game maker studio 2 gml the animation is set to a ridiculously fast speed. The draw event is as follows.

```
    var cx = camera_get_view_x(view_camera[1]);
    var cy = camera_get_view_y(view_camera[1]);
    var cw = camera_get_view_width(view_camera[1]);


    if (global.player_health >= 1)
    {
    draw_sprite(heartSmallSpr, -1, cx + (cw / 2) - 64, cy + 25)
    }

    if (global.player_health >= 2)
    {
    draw_sprite(heartSmallSpr, -1, cx + (cw / 2), cy + 25)
    } 

    if (global.player_health >= 3)
    {
    draw_sprite(heartSmallSpr, -1, cx + (cw / 2) + 64, cy + 25)
    }
```

The sprite has two frames set to 1 second but when the draw_sprite(); code is set to -1 or sprite_index it plays it is about 100 frames per second. I have tried setting the speed of the sprite but it does not do anything.

Comment: not related to your current problem, but are you making an if-statement for each bit of health? If it's just 3 lives, it's not a problem, but if you're expanding this, try using a for-loop instead.

Comment: I am only doing three lives at the moment but I might look into looping if it is more compact I will definitely go with it.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I will just make a simple timer that subtracts 1 from a variable every frame and when it is equal to 0 I will make it change the sprite_index. This is probably the long way to do things but I am still open to any suggestions about the code above.

Comment: Just a question, but if you only want to use one frame, then why does the sprite has two frames anyways? is it part of the animation, or do you only want to set the other frame when a specific condition is met? I think it's better to make two seperate sprites for the frames, and then change the sprite_index to the other frame when that's needed. Though, that really depends on what the second frame is about.

Comment: I want to use both frames in a constant animation no matter what the conditions are I want it to always be playing the animation but I can't because of the speed the command plays the animation

Answer (score 0):

Just set the sprite index to 0, "sprite_index" is the image of which it needs to draw. i dont know why its running super fast if you set it to -1, but since there is no -1 image index, it should give you an error. Just set it to whatever you frame you want it to draw. If you are wanting it to play an animation, you cant use draw_sprite without setting up a variable to run through all the image index's.

Answer (score 0):

If image_index shows you a heightened animation speed, it's either your room speed or you have somewhere in your game something manually changing either the image_speed or the image_index.

Maybe check if you have a left-over of some other code that you used to change those variables?